# Why do I need to have a Selenium Server instead of calling the WebDriver implementation directly

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

**My Situation**

I am trying to run automated headless browser tests with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and the provided [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). Of course, I need some kind of a library that wraps the [WebDriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) implementation because I don't want to call the API implementation myself. During my investigation for some kind of a library for that, I stumbled across things like [WebDriverIO](http://webdriver.io/). Reading the [documentation it says that I need to install a standalone selenum server](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/install.html) in order to make it work.

**My Question**

Why do I need a dedicated [Selenium server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) for that?

Isn't there a library that calls the HTTP API of the [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) directly?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is the wrapper to talk to HTTP-API of many browsers.

You can talk directly to GhostDriver or Chrome .. but have to talk to their individual API's.   You can use selenium to easily match your preferred code binding (python, java, js, ruby, c#, whateves) to the desired browser by using Selenium to drive the browser.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

Otherwise, you'd want to connect to the GhostDriver and drive it yourself.

Comment: According to the Selenium JavaScript docu(seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index‌​.html) a Selenium Server is not always needed. So I guess the WebDriverIO framework just prescribes the setup with a server. But why? I really don't see the benefit of introducing a standalone Selenium server on my local machine just to run the tests.

Comment: Understood, then you would need to connect to each browser's remote driver manually.  Since you are only picking PhantomJS, you can write directly to Phantom.  Selenium bindings are tiny, and you could be done by now.